# Assigning numbers 1-7 to a list of dates?

Tags: r

Beginner here so bear with me: I have a list of dates that I want to assign a number from 1-7:

```
3/27/2019   1

3/28/2019   2

3/29/2019   3

3/30/2019   4

3/31/2019   5

4/1/2019    6

4/2/2019    7

4/3/2019    

4/4/2019
```

It should start back at `1` on `4/3/2019` and keep going until the list ends. What function could I use to do this?

Comment: You're looking for the function `rep()`.

Comment: Are these meant to represent days of the week? If so, better to state that specifically and use a function designed for that purpose. Then the output doesn't depend on your data set being ordered properly with no days missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your dates are stored in a dataframe:

```
dates_df$numbers <- rep(1:7, length.out = nrow(dates_df))
```

rep() function that will replicate the first argument
1:7 - Creates a vector of the sequence from 1 to 7
length.out - Argument that will replicate 1:7 until it is length.out long
nrow(dates_df) - Want the 1:7 sequence to be repeated until its the same length as your date vector